# Make a hibernate criteria that return all objects with same objects on sublist

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

My problem is:

I have a class that contains a specific list of objects and I need to return all the class objects whose list contains a specific sublist that I passed as param.
For example:

```
class A{

List<Object> b;
}

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("b.name", new String[]{"name 1","name 2"}))
return criteria.list();
```

But, this returns the same object of class A twice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Subqueries.exists()` to fetch all parent objects which have at least one child with specific characteristics, try something like this.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a1");
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class, "b");
detachedCriteria.createAlias("b.a", "a2");
detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("a1.id", "a2.id"));
detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("name", new String[]{"name 1","name 2"}))

criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(detachedCriteria));
return criteria.list();
```